# OpenLayers WMSGetFeatureInfo Windows Mobile

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, getfeatureinfo, windows-phone

I have built an app using Phonegap build that uses OpenLayers 2.13.1 with WMS layers from GeoServer and I have a WMSGetFeatureInfo control set up. When I click a point on Windows phone 8, the error I get is `"Unable to get property 'documentElement' of undefined or null reference" at line 1308.`

I think it might be a cross-domain issue. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I've just hit this problem. I found it was only with the Edge browser. It worked okay with IE10 and below. You can work around this by adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
```

to the head section of your page.